# Vaadin doesn't load my login page in a Spring app

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin

I'm using `Spring Boot 3.1` and `Vaadin 24` for my project. I'm trying to use the vaadin login page from the instruction, but opening it in Firefox shows that the login page is a part of another web site

Here is my security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class WebSecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurity {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userService);
        final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = authenticationManagerBuilder.build();

        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    try {
                        auth
                                .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/registration")).permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/login")).permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/account/**")).authenticated()
                                .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/users/**")).hasAuthority(Role.ADMIN.toString())
                                .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/images/*.png")).permitAll();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error("Error setting security logout", e);
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                })
                .formLogin(page ->
                {
                    try {
                        page.loginPage("/login")
                                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/main")
                                .successForwardUrl("/main")
                                .permitAll()
                                .init(http);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Unsuccessful creating login page", e);
                    }
                })
                .rememberMe(page -> page
                        .userDetailsService(userService)
                        .useSecureCookie(true))
                .logout(LogoutConfigurer::permitAll)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .sessionManagement(sess ->
                        sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED));
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);
        super.configure(http);
    }
}
```

and here is the login view config:

```
@Route("login")
@PageTitle("Login | Interval Words Learning")
@AnonymousAllowed
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver {
    private final LoginForm login = new LoginForm();

    public LoginView() {
        addClassName("login-view");
        setSizeFull();
        setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
        setJustifyContentMode(JustifyContentMode.CENTER);

        login.setAction("login");
        add(new H1("Interval Words Learning"), login);

        login.addLoginListener(event -> {
            if (!event.getSource().isError()) {
                UI.getCurrent().navigate("/main");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent beforeEnterEvent) {
        if (beforeEnterEvent.getLocation()
                .getQueryParameters()
                .getParameters()
                .containsKey("error")) {
            login.setError(true);
        }
    }
}
```

`UserService` is a bean with in-memory stored users.
After opening my app, I'm getting such an error:

```
Firefox can't open this page

To ensure your safety, localhost has not allowed Firefox to display the page because it is embedded in another site. To see this page, you need to open it in a new window.
```

and opening it in a new window makes nothing.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: My assumption is that this setting `requestMatchers(antMatcher("/login")).permitAll()` makes your login view to require the user to be logged in first in order to access it. Also I am not sure about the necessity of the other settings there.